# vb.net chnage textbox.text value with for-next loop

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, click

I intend to get the  value of a Textbox (TNumb.Text) and then use this value (an integer) in other buttons (Private Subs). The number should start at 1 and end at a comboboxvalue (CmbMax.Text) specified by the user. Starting from 1, the program should run through the code lines, perform clicks of the following buttons - (BFirst, BSecond, BFinal). When done with the clicks of these buttons in succession, the TNumb.Text should increase by 1 to 2 and then BFirst, BSecond & BFinal are clicked. Afterward this, another increment of 1 should be done and TNumb should increase again by 1 to 3. This should continue till TMax.Text is reached. All the three buttons should be clicked too. I have used a for-next loop and several other modifications but haven't been successful. Let me also add that in the Load event of the form, I made TNumb.Text=0. The major problem is that when TNumb.text = 1 runs, the value is not increased to 2 for the use and subsequent clicking of the other three buttons. Help will be greatly appreciated. Below is the unsuccessful code I have used:

`

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e as EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
For j As Integer  = 1 to CInt(CmbMax.Text)

TLine.Text = j

Dim h as string = "10:00:00 AM"
Dim g as string = TimeOfDay
Dim w as string = tCpyT.Text
Dim n as string = tTmNow.Text

If h = g or w = n Then

BFirst.PerformClick()
BSecond.PerformClick()
BFinal.PerformClick()

Next

End Sub
```

`

Comment: I started writing an answer to this question, but there is just so much bad code and bad concepts going on here. Rather than telling us how you want something to happen, why don't you explain what it is that you want to accomplish? I guarantee you there is a much better way than what you're currently trying.

Comment: Hello, David. What I want to accomplish is to get the textbox value to increase by 1, run a code, increase by 1 again and then run the same code. 

Unfortunately, I’m a novice in this area. I’d be more than grateful if you help me out. Maybe I haven’t been able to explain/express myself properly but I do not have anything to hide. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have the button's setup in the first place? Can/should the user be able to click those buttons at any point or are they there to simply represent a block of code that should be ran during your loop?

Comment: The program, is ideally supposed to run unattended. The user won’t click any of those buttons. When the timer ticks, those buttons are clicked programmatically. So now, in the loop, I call these three buttons that are Private Subs in the program. Thank you.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Comment: I don't get what the timer is supposed to do. What is the interval set to? Will the For loop complete before the Timer ticks again?

Comment: Hello, Mary. Thank you for your directive. The timer ticks to verify if the TimeOfDay is equal to the a set time. When this condition is met, then these buttons are clicked to get the program to process a file on daily basis without the program being attended to.

Comment: I don't see any code checking the time of day and comparing the it to anything. Your code will just run whenever the Timer interval is reached. What is the interval? I would use Windows scheduler to run your program at the appointed time. It seems not right to keep a program running all the time when it only has to do work once a day.

Comment: We will not be notified of your responses unless you put @Mary in your comment.

Comment: Hello @Mary. I have modified the code to include the time check. I did not include them initially because I felt it wouldn't change anything (sorry about that) the subs because it will make my submission bulky.

Comment: @Mary. In the past, TLine.Text was fixed to just 1. Now the program has to run and process for TLine.Text = 1, TLine.Text = 2, TLine.Text = 3 ... TLine.Text = CmbMax.Text. I hope I am clearer now.

Comment: You still haven't told me what the Timer interval is and I have asked at least twice.

Comment: @Mary the Timer interval is a second.

Comment: @Mary the 1 second-Timer ticks to check if the TimeOfDay = tCpyT or 10:00:00 hours.